# resize hashtable and keep elements from old table

Tags: c, hashtable

I want to create a new function where I need to create a new hashtable once the old hashtable is full, add all the elements from the old hashtable to it and then delete the old hashtable. I need to begin with entering the new tablesize and the index in the new hashtable should go form index 0 --> last index in the old hashtable.

```
static int hash(Key key, int tablesize)
{
return key % tablesize; 
}

int newHashTable(HashTable* htable, const Key key) {

printf("Enter new tablesize:");
scanf("%d", &htable->size);

-----THIS IS WHERE THE NEW CODE SHOULD BE--------

}

static int linearProbe(const HashTable* htable, const Key key, int* indexOut)
{

*indexOut = hash(key, htable->size);
int kollision = 0;

 
while (htable->table[*indexOut].key != UNUSED && htable->table[*indexOut].key != key) {
    //om alla platser är upptagna
    if (kollision == htable->size) {

        newHashTable(htable, key);
        return kollision;
    }
    
    *indexOut = (*indexOut + 1) % htable->size;
    
    kollision++;
}
return kollision;
}

HashTable createHashTable(unsigned int size)
{
HashTable htable;
htable.size = size;

htable.table = calloc(size, sizeof(struct Bucket));

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    htable.table[i].key = UNUSED;
}

return htable;
}

int insertElement(HashTable* htable, const Key key, const Value value)
{
 int index;

int kollision = linearProbe(htable, key, &index);

if (kollision != htable->size) {
    
    htable->table[index].value = value;
    htable->table[index].key = key;
    return kollision;
}

return kollision;
```

}

Comment: I've done the hashtable with open addressing. I also have a testfile, where I select the tablesize in the beginning. So yes, in my case it can be full and happens when a collision occurs.@PaulOgilvie

Comment: 1) loop over the old hash table 2) if cell contains UNUSED: skip it 3) lookup the desired slot in the new hash table 4) insert {key,value} there 5) delete the old hash table 6) profit!